# Sendgrid will only send utf-8 attachments

Tags: php, utf-8, encode, sendgrid

I've created an employment application that allows applicants to upload their resume in pdf, doc, or docx extensions. I then email their information and resume to Human Resources using Sendgrid.

I've found through testing that when sending the email I receive an error:

*Parameter attachment[resume.pdf] is not utf8*

How can I fix this issues, should I encode every file that is uploaded to utf-8 before attaching it to the email? Will this create any issues or severally modify an users uploaded resume?

Here is my PHP Curl code I use to send via the SendGrid API:
(Note: I have to use the REST API, SMTP is not configured on the clients web server)

```
    <?php

        $mail['from'] = 'humanresources@email.org';
                    $mail['fromname'] = 'Human Resources';
                    $mail['to'] = 'person@email.com';



                    $mail['subject'] = character_limiter('Employment: '. $application['position'], 50);

                    $mail['html'] = '<p><strong>Name:</strong> '.$application['firstname'].' '.$application['lastname'].'</p>';
                    $mail['html'] .= '<p><strong>Position:</strong> '.$application['position'].'</p>';
                    $mail['html'] .= '<p><strong>Date:</strong> '.mdate('%m/%d/%Y %g:%i %A', $application['timestamp_saved']).'</p>';
                    $mail['html'] .= '<p><strong>Email:</strong> '.$application['email'].'</p>';


                    $mail['files['.$application['pdf'].']'] = '@saved_applications/'. $application['pdf'];



                    //Sendgrid Credientals
                    $mail['api_user']  = 'sendgrid_user';
                    $mail['api_key']   = 'sendgrid_pass';

                    print_r($mail);

                    // Generate curl request
                    $session = curl_init('https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json');
                    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mail);
                    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                    // obtain response
                    $response = curl_exec($session);
                    curl_close($session);

                    // print everything out
                    $output = json_decode($response, TRUE);

                    print_r($output);

?>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug on sendgrid end, have you tried their support?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have should work (and worked when I tested it).

You may want to use the [PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php), rather than flat cURL. You'll be able to [send attachments](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html#-Using-Attachments), from the web Web API by doing the following:

```
<?php
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid('username', 'password');
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
    $mail->
    addTo('humanresources@email.org')->
    ...
    addAttachment('saved_applications/'. $application['pdf']);
    $sendgrid->web->send($mail);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using sendgrid's web services API to send these messages, simply use phpmailer and send the messages through sendgrid by way of SMTP using their outgoing mail server smtp.sendgrid.net.  I'm sure you won't get this error if you send the messages this way.  See example at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.

Comment: Using SMTP was the route I wanted to take at first. But the hosting provider the client is using doesn't have SMTP configured on their web server :(

Comment: With phpmailer, you don't need an SMTP server running on the host.  It will send the message out using a remote SMTP server, such as Sendgrid's smtp.sendgrid.net.

Comment: And it's easy to use, simple to setup.  Just copy 3 files to your hosting account (which get included in your PHP scripts), and use the example at the link I copied above as a boilerplate for sending a message (with attachments).